# hide div when click outside using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I write this code to hide div when user click anywhere in body outside this div.. but is wrong what is the problem ?

```
$('body').click(function() {
   $('.mydiv').hide();
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403615/use-jquery-to-hide-a-div-when-the-user-clicks-outside-of-it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If u give like this

```
$('body').click(function() {    
    $('.mydiv').hide(); 
});
```

This DIV will get Hidden even if you click inside the DIV.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried replacing

```
hideMenu()
```

with

```
$('#cMenu').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving that function to the `body` `onclick` event, you can make two container divs: One for everything in the body above your menu, and one for everything below your menu within the `body` tag, and give those two divs the `onclick` function you're currently giving to the `body`.